# Initialising a QueryDict.fromkeys

Tags: python, django

We can initialise a new dict instance from a list of keys:

```
>>> dict.fromkeys(['spam', 'spam', 'potato'])
{'potato': None, 'spam': None}
```

And a querydict **is a** dict, so this should work, right?

```
>>> QueryDict.fromkeys(['spam', 'spam', 'potato'])
TypeError: __init__() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Of course I can do something lame like `QueryDict('spam&spam&potato')`, but my question: is the `.fromkeys` method usable at all, or completely broken?

If the former, how do you use it?  If the latter, why wasn't it explicitly disabled in the subclass?

Comment: Why would you want to use it at all?

Comment: I can't reproduce that error. It seems weird anyway, none of the classes in the inheritance chain have any required arguments for `__init__()`.

Comment: This is indeed an interesting question! Actually, on the documentation, these clearly list the dict methods which have be overloaded and have a different behaviour or calling arguments and they call these "exceptions" (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict). However, .fromkeys is not in the list, therefore, it should still work the same way.

Comment: Can you write django version and module of `QueryDict` class?

Comment: The documentation for `QueryDict` states that it is, by default, immutable. In my process of testing, calling `fromkeys` was throwing an `AttributeError` rather than a `TypeError`. Perhaps show the full traceback?

Comment: @Wondercricket: It has no traceback because `fromkeys` is implemented in C. It tries to call `__init__` with incorrect numer of parameters (missing query_string for QueryDict) and therefore no Python source code is called inside C. AttributeError is for Python 3, TypeError for Python 2 but this difference is not important

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tl;dr [`QueryDict.fromkeys`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/_modules/django/http/request/#QueryDict.fromkeys) will start working in the Django 1.11 release.

At PyCon 2016 I had the opportunity to speak with some core Django developers, we agreed the inherited method is broken and violates the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).  At one of the [sprints](https://us.pycon.org/2016/community/sprints/) I was able to scratch this itch and patch the QueryDict class.

Here's the relevant [commit](https://github.com/django/django/commit/5ebebd1159b4bacfce1999e41831081679b6f35a) and [issue](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/26707), the fix is now merged into master and [already in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.fromkeys).  I used an implementation similar to the first proposal from [hynekcer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33705025/674039).

Comment: Thanks for excellent work on the issue and for the theoretic context. Please fix the link to *Liskov substitution principle*. (It should be google or wiki?) The issue is a great example of LSP that [no immutable type can be a subtype of a mutable ancestor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle#Principle), but some mutable type can be a subtype of immutable ancestor. So if we break some consequences of LSP (as we frequently do for usefulness), at least the constructors should not be broken.

Answer (score 1):

The problem depends also on Django version. You use Django 1.7.x or older that requires the positional parameter `query_string` for QueryDict. It is fixed in Django 1.8 where this parameter is optional.

The second problem is that `QueryDict` creates by default an *immutable* instance and there is no way how to pass `mutable=True` through `fromkeys`. The keys can not be added to immutable and the method fails also in Django 1.8.

It can be fixed this way:

```
from django.http.request import QueryDict

class MyQueryDict(QueryDict):

    @classmethod
    def fromkeys(cls, seq, value='', encoding=None):
        result = cls('', mutable=True, encoding=encoding)
        for key in seq:
            result.appendlist(key, value)  # or result.update(key, value)
        return result
```

It is implemented more complicated in order to reflect repeated keys. The default value is the empty string because it doesn't make sense to convert it to string 'None' like `'potato=None&spam=None&spam=None'` by `urlencode()` method. The default result QueryDict should be the same as `QueryDict('potato&spam&spam')`.

The presented solution is so strange that `raise NotImplemented()` would be a more straightforward "implementation". (EDIT: I don't expect that anything more is useful enough to be accepted to Django code base) However I must agree with you, it is a bug with mysterious messages. Unimplemented functionalities are usually undocumented if they don't require a warning note because they can be found endless many.

Other solution would be to modify `__init__` only:

```
class MyQueryDict(QueryDict):

    def __init__(self, query_string=None, mutable=True, encoding=None):
        super(MyQueryDict, self).__init__(query_string=query_string,
                                          mutable=mutable,
                                          encoding=encoding)
```

because immutable QueryDict instances are frequently impractical and even one half of internal use in Django is with mutable QueryDict instances.

Comment: Hi, it's in master now (similar to your first implementation) --> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/_modules/django/http/request/#QueryDict.fromkeys

Answer (score 0):

Although `QueryDict` is a dict, the main issue is that it's an immutable dict by default, in addition you're not getting a very good error message (I'm actually using Django 1.8+ and getting a more clear message 'This QueryDict instance is immutable').

That said, if you are creating your own `QueryDict` instance you can declare it to be mutable:

```
mutable_query_dict = QueryDict(mutable=True)
# Calling fromkeys directly also throws an 'instance is immutable' error, so it looks like a subtle bug 
#! mutable_query_dict.fromkeys(['spam', 'spam', 'potato']) 
# But you can always use the update() method like this
mutable_query_dict.update(dict.fromkeys(['spam', 'spam', 'potato']))
```

If you have a pre-existing `QueryDict`, then you can create a copy of it, which automatically makes in mutable:

```
regular_query_dict = QueryDict()
# Calling fromkeys() or update() throws an immutable error 
#! regular_query_dict.fromkeys(['spam', 'spam', 'potato'])
#! regular_query_dict.update(dict.fromkeys(['spam', 'spam', 'potato'])) 
# Create a copy of the regular QueryDict to make it mutable
copy_of_regular_query_dict = regular_query_dict.copy()
# Calling fromkeys directly also throws an 'instance is immutable' error, so it looks like a subtle bug 
#! copy_of_regular_query_dict.fromkeys(['spam', 'spam', 'potato'])
# But you can always use the update() method like this
copy_of_regular_query_dict.update(dict.fromkeys(['spam', 'spam','potato']))
```

In summary, it does like a very subtle bug is present when invoking `fromkeys()` on a `QueryDict`. But you can get past it using the `update()` method and also realizing you have to make the `QueryDict` mutable.

Comment: No you can't do this, because `QueryDict` is a multi-value dict.  The fact that the key 'spam' is present twice will be destroyed at the stage of  `dict.fromkeys(['spam', 'spam','potato'])`